# connect: connection timed out

Tags: postgresql, go

I have successfully connected to a Postgres database using the go sql package:

```golang
...
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
```

I then use the returned database to execute a (long running) query:

```golang
rows, err := db.Query(...)
```

And am getting the error:

```
dial tcp xx.xxx.xxx.xx:5432: connect: connection timed out
```

I have a couple of questions regarding this:

1. why is the connection timing out?
2. is there anything I can do to prevent it timing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sql.Open() may just validate its arguments **without creating a connection** to
>   the database. To verify that the data source name is valid, **call Ping**.

The `sql.Open()` function has only created an object, your pool is currently empty. In simple words connection with the database hasn't been established yet.

You need to call `db.Ping()` to make sure your pool has a working connection.

Comment: thanks - so just to clarify, by calling `db.Query(...)` I have created a new database client, but no connections have yet been created? Therefore, when `db.Query(...)` is called, an attempt is made to create a connection and (for whatever reason) one isn't created within the (specified?) time, resulting in a connection timeout? I think I got the wrong end of the stick, assuming connection timeout meant the connection was closed after a set period of time, but in fact it was never open!

Comment: My understanding is that whenever you call some function that needs to communicate with the database, the first thing they do is look for an free connection in the pool and use that. If there isn't any free connection then it opens a new connection. When the function completes it ultimately returns the connection back to pool.